# Filter array by other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, include

I have two arrays

```
firstArray = ['10','12'];
secondArray = [{"id":"10", "name":"name 10"}, {"id":"11", "name":"name 11"}, {"id":"12", "name":"name 12"}];
```

Here I want to delete entries `{"id":"11", "name":"name 11"}` from my second array because the ID 11 is not in my first array. So the result should be

```
secondArray = [{"id":"10", "name":"name 10"}, {"id":"12", "name":"name 12"}];
```

How can I do this ?

I am not sure, the following code can give the correct output

```js
const firstArray = ['10','12'];
let secondArray = [{"id":"10", "name":"name 10"}, {"id":"11", "name":"name 11"}, {"id":"12", "name":"name 12"}];
secondArray = secondArray.filter((o) => firstArray.findIndex((obj)=> obj.id === o.id)!=-1 );
console.log(secondArray);
```

Comment: `firstArray` contains numbers. `obj.id === o.id` won't work. It's `obj === o.id`. VTC as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter with a check if the array includes the wanted `id`.

```js
const
    unwanted = ['10', '12'],
    data = [{ id: "10", name: "name 10" }, { id: "11", name: "name 11" }, { id: "12", name: "name 12" }],
    result = data.filter(({ id }) => unwanted.includes(id));

console.log(result);
```